# chemformula: escaped input isn't treated as such

Tags: chemmacros

When using `'foo'` or `"foo"` in order to provide chemformula with input which shouldn't be treated as part of a chemical formula within `\ch{}`, numbers are still being typeset subscript. The code

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,paper=a4]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\begin{document}
\ch{Pd(0)L4} \ch{Pd'(0)'L4} \ch{Pd"(0)"L4} \ch{Pd$(0)$L4} \ch{Pd\textrm{(0)}L4} \ch{Pd(}0\ch{)L4} 
\end{document}
```

gives the following when compiling with the latest MiKTeX distribution (pdflatex):

[image]

As you can see,  only the last dirty workaround invoking `\ch{Pd(}0\ch{)L4}` gives the desired output. I also tried to fool chemformula by entering 0 in math mode which didn't work either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to put a space before and after the escaping sequence, both in text and in math mode. That is, for example

```
\ch{Pd '(0)' L4}
```

instead of

```
\ch{Pd'(0)'L4}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,paper=a4]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\begin{document}
\ch{Pd(0)L4} \ch{Pd '(0)' L4} \ch{Pd "(0)" L4} \ch{Pd $(0)$ L4} \ch{Pd\textrm{(0)}L4} \ch{Pd(}0\ch{)L4}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

As cgnieder has noticed, in math mode some spacing is inserted. To remove this, set

```
\setchemformula{math-space=0em}
```

globally, or, to have it locally

```
\ch[math-space=0em]{Pd $(0)$ L4}
```

Comment: This is true for *every* input type, by the way :)

Comment: Also notice the difference for math output: it is followed by a space (which can be controlled through an option...).

Comment: @cgnieder Is the edit OK?

Comment: Sure :) There is also `\setchemformula{math-space=0em}` which can be used without `chemmacros`. Also, the option can be used directly: `\ch[math-space=0em]{...}`

Comment: Thank you very much. The examples from the chemformula documentation worked for me, too. But I couldn't figure out that these spaces are required!